# How to tell three Javascript objects that everything is loaded

Tags: javascript

I have three custom javascript object instances.

1. object 1
2. object 2
3. object 3

Object 1 and 2 are instances of the same object and contain kineticjs object inside of them as properties. They are used for visualizing. Object 3 is an intstance of a different object that gets its properties from the backend and stores them and saves them back.

When object 1 and two are created I use a function to bind some dom elements events with some of the kineticjs objects inside object 1 and objet 2, so when a value of the dom elements change something must be visualized using the kineticjs objects.

something like

```
function afterObject1 (){
    //here some $('selector').on('change', function) happens
}

function afterObject2 (){
    //here some $('selector').on('change', function) happens
}
```

and then on ready function

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    object1 = ObjectWithKineticJS(afterObject1);
    object2 = ObjectWithKIneticJS(afterObject2);
});
```

so I make sure everything happens after object1 and two are initialized.

in my ready function I also have the following

```
object3 = new ObjectForBackend()
```

I have a method of object3 that is used to update the dom elements with values taken from the backend. I want this method to be called after both functions(afterObject1, afterObject2) have finished. Is there a way to achieve that? I have t9o say dealing with objects is getting a bit frustrated for me when using javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing that you already use jQuery, the neatest way to go about this is probably to use its Deferred/Promise setup. I'm rather new to that myself, but [jQuery.when](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) seems to do exactly what you need:

```
var d1 = new $.Deferred();
var d2 = new $.Deferred();

$.when( d1, d2 ).done(function ( v1, v2 ) {    
    console.log( v1 ); // "Fish"    
    console.log( v2 ); // "Pizza"
}); 

d1.resolve( "Fish" );
d2.resolve( "Pizza" );
```